# Add a bundle on a Symfony 3.2 website online

Tags: php, symfony

my Symfony website works very well. But I want to add a bundle. I installed it on dev mode and it works correctly. When I install it on the server adding it in AppKernel.php, composer.json, composer.lock and in the vendor directory, updating composer vendor, the website responds with an error 500. 
I removed the cache.
Can you help me?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Just some idea. More information are highly appreciated. Also, in order to meet the requirements of this site, you should tell us what you've done before in order to fix your issue. Also, post error logs.

Answer (score 1):

There are some elements not intended for production use, and that's the reason why they are used in dev only. Also, in dev you see any errors in the browser, but in prod, you get a 500 error, so you have to take a look at var/logs/prod.log. Also, you have to clear the cache with --env=prod.

You didn't specify the bundle that gives the problem. Take a look at its documentation for if there are any drawbacks in production use.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your advices.
I've finally found the answer on my own.
First, I ran the website URL adding /app_dev.php : the error was more precise. The bundle class was not found.
I realized that my composer files in vendor/composer were not updated with the new bundle name.